# Enabling RBAC on Kubernetes on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to enable RBAC on my k8s cluster on azure. I ssh'ed into my master node and edited the `kube-apiserver.yaml` with the `--authorization-mode=RBAC` flag. Then I delete the `kube-apiserver` pod in order to restart the api server. However, when upon restart the `--authorization-mode=RBAC` config is ignored. Anybody have any advice?

Also the api server configuration is set to `--v=10` and the image is `v1.6.6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to generate a cluster that would allow me to enable RBAC on azure by generating an arm template using Azure Container Service Engine:
https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine

By using the above library I could create a new arm template with RBAC enabled and then use the Azure CLI to create a RBAC, configurable Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Had to move to `acs-engine`. Saved me hours. Now testing if it supports cluster updates.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the pod is not enough. You need to restart kubelet in order for the new options to be applied.

```
   systemctl restart kubelet
```

Comment: I appreciate the response. However that ended up crashing the cluster. I wonder if Azure by default imposes some restrictions when a cluster is created using their tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-walkthrough