# How to enable RBAC on existing Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authorization/rbac/) documentation of Kubernetes is says:

```
To enable RBAC, start the apiserver with --authorization-mode=RBAC
```

How do you upgrade an existing cluster and/or how to see if RBAC is enabled?

I have created my cluster on Google k8 clusters and only have kubectl.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552593/enabling-rbac-on-kubernetes-on-azure) but it kind of did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google public documentation addresses [how to use RBAC](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control) on Google Kubernetes Engine Clusters. For GKE Clusters running 1.6 or 1.7, you must create or update your cluster with the --no-enable-legacy-authorization flag. For version 1.8 or later, legacy authorization is disabled by default.

You can update your cluster using [gcloud container clusters update [CLUSTER_NAME] --no-enable-legacy-authorization](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update).

The RBAC API is already enabled with GKE (rbac.authorization.k8s.io), so you can start creating objects.

Answer (score 4):

Could you SSH to the master node/nodes and edit `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`

You should see something like below in the file >

```
command:
    - "/hyperkube"
    - "apiserver"
    - "--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota"
    - "--address=0.0.0.0"
    - "--allow-privileged"
    - "--insecure-port=8080"
    - "--secure-port=443"
    - "--cloud-provider=azure"
    - "--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/azure.json"
    - "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/16"
    - "--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379"
    - "--etcd-quorum-read=true"
    - "--advertise-address=10.240.255.15"
    - "--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.crt"
    - "--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
    - "--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt"
    - "--service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
    - "--storage-backend=etcd2"
    - "--v=4"
```

Just add `--authorization-mode=RBAC` and reboot the node and it should work.

Something like

```
command:
        - "/hyperkube"
        - "apiserver"
        - "--admission-control=NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,ResourceQuota"
        - "--address=0.0.0.0"
        - "--allow-privileged"
        - "--insecure-port=8080"
        - "--secure-port=443"
        - "--cloud-provider=azure"
        - "--cloud-config=/etc/kubernetes/azure.json"
        - "--service-cluster-ip-range=10.0.0.0/16"
        - "--etcd-servers=http://127.0.0.1:2379"
        - "--etcd-quorum-read=true"
        - "--advertise-address=10.240.255.15"
        - "--tls-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.crt"
        - "--tls-private-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
        - "--client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/ca.crt"
        - "--service-account-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/apiserver.key"
        - "--storage-backend=etcd2"
        - "--v=4"
        - "--authorization-mode=RBAC"
```

Note that is this surely not official way but it did work for me running Kubernetes 1.8

Comment: This won't work with Google Kubernetes Engine because the Master node is hosted and managed by Google. We do not have access to it.

Comment: Ah sorry, get it now. I think RBAC needs to be enabled in master node somehow as that is where this setting lives

Comment: Completely agree, this fix works for basically any other config than with Google